# JWT How should I protected endpoints for user and admin?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, vue.js, authentication, jwt

I wanted to ask about good JWT authentication practices. I need to protect half of my endpoints in my spring backend where only administrator may call them from my rest Vue api and rest of them may be called only from vue native application where users will be logged in. How should I do it?
Best regards!

Comment: There are different approaches. You better search the web. I have implemented the same thing using spring filter. here is example https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-custom-filter

Comment: How to do it with already implemented JWT?

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using spring security authorities in your userdetails,  so an admin user will have and admin role and a normal user will have a user role.

Then the endpoints can be protected based on the roles

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
public List<Foo> findAll() { ... }
...
```